# Projective cover of $M$ equals projective cover of $M/\operatorname{Rad}(M)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Take a module $M \in \Lambda$-mod, where $\Lambda$ is a finite dimensional algebra over a field $K$. Knowing that $M/\operatorname{Rad}(M) = S_1 \oplus \dots \oplus S_r$, with $S_i$ simple, and that $\operatorname{Rad}(M)$ is superfluous in $M$, I have to show that the projective cover of $M$ is equal to the projective cover of $M/\operatorname{Rad}(M)$.
Can someone help me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2925614/show-that-a-finitely-generated-module-m-over-an-artinian-ring-r-admits-a-pro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following argument is taken from Ringel/Schröer's representation theory book project. At the moment, a link can be found [here](http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/schroer/dst/dst_2009.pdf). It is Lemma 17.16.

Let $P_i$ be the projective cover of $S_i$ and $P:=\bigoplus P_i$. Then there is an isomorphism $P/\operatorname{Rad}(P)\to M/\operatorname{Rad}(M)$. Thus there is a morphism $P\to M/\operatorname{Rad}(M)$ and an epimorphism $M\twoheadrightarrow M/\operatorname{Rad}(M)$. By the universal property of projective modules there exists a module homomorphism $p: P\to M$ making the appropriate diagram commutative.

Now you have $\operatorname{Im}(p)+\operatorname{Rad}(M)=M$ by commutativity of the diagram and the fact that $P\to P/\operatorname{Rad}(P)$ is an epimorphism. Since $\operatorname{Rad}(M)$ is superfluous we have that $p$ is an epimorphism.

Now the induced morphism $p_*:P/\operatorname{Rad}(P)\to M/\operatorname{Rad}(M)$ is injective (by definition of $p$. Hence the kernel of $p$ is contained in the radical of $P$. Now $\operatorname{Rad}(P)$ superfluous implies that $\ker p$ is superfluous and that is the definition of projective cover.

Comment: Thanks, it's almost clear. But, I can't get why the morphism $p_\ast$ is injective. Is that the same map that you said to be an isomorphism at the beginning?

Comment: @freedfromthereal Yes, this is the isomorphism we started with.