# Show that a finitely generated module $M$ over an Artinian ring $R$ admits a projective cover

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, homological-algebra

I was asked to show. *Let $R$ an Artinian ring and $M$ a left $R$-module finitely generated. Show that $M$ admits a projective cover.*

**My Attempt:** I take any $L$ $R$-module projective finitely generated and an epimorphism $f:L \longrightarrow M$. Then I considered $\mathcal{S}:=\left\{N\subseteq \ker f \mid N \text{ is sub-module of } L \text{ and } f_{N}:L/N\longrightarrow M \text{ is essential epimorphism} \right\} $, then $\mathcal{S}\neq\emptyset$ ($\ker f\in\cal{S}$) and like $L$ is an Artinian $R$-module, exist $X$ minimal with this property, now, I'm trying to prove that $(L/X,f_X)$ is the proyective cover of $M$, but I'm stuck showing that $L/X$ is projective. Any hint?, Thank for your help guys.

Comment: Maybe you can first do this every simple module has a projective cover.Then for any finite generated module $M$ consider $M\rightarrow M/radM$,then you need to find a projective cover of $M/radM$ ,then you get a lifting.Show this lifting is projective cover.

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/311859/projective-cover-of-m-equals-projective-cover-of-m-operatornameradm