# Existence of Projective Cover

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, modules, projective-module, injective-module

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional algebra and let $M$ be a finite dimensional $A$-module. Then $M$ has a projective cover and I am trying to prove this.

> Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a module class and $X$ a module.
>
> A $\mathcal{C}$-precover of $X$ is a morphism $\theta : C \rightarrow X$ with $C \in \mathcal{C}$, such that for any $\theta' : C' \rightarrow X$ with $C' \in \mathcal{C}$, there is $\phi : C' \rightarrow C$ with $\theta' = \theta \phi$.
>
> A $\mathcal{C}$-cover of $X$ is a right minimal $\mathcal{C}$-precover.

I already know that $X$ has a $\mathcal{C}$-cover when it has a $\mathcal{C}$-precover. So I only need to prove that $M$ has a projective precover.

For some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we can find an epimorphism $\theta: A^n \rightarrow M$. If I now take a morphism $\theta': P \rightarrow M$, $P$ projective, I need to find a morphism $\phi: P \rightarrow A^n$ such that $\theta' = \theta \phi$. How do I get this $\phi$?

And my second questions is, is the proof for the existence of injective envelopes in this case similar?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Injective envelopes always exist, whereas projective covers do not exist in the general case, even for finitely generated modules. Thus you are almost certainly going to need to use the fact that $A$ is a finite dimensional algebra.

Comment: @jgon that's a good hint, thank you. Do you have an idea how I can do that?

Comment: @Chaser01 There are going to be infinitely many $\theta$ of the form you're suggesting, and you can choose each one to be "more wasteful" than the next, so it is not a good candidate.  You need to get a better candidate.

Comment: This is a special case of a [different post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2925614/29335), but that one admittedly does not have a solution posted.

Comment: Actually *every* right module of a right Artinian ring has a projective cover. But maybe there's a nice elementary solution for this special case.  There's a Zorn's Lemma argument that works for the proof for the injective envelope that doesn't dualize to projective covers.  Having the descending chain condition is a substitute for that, especially if you have a finitely generate module over a ring with the DCC, so that the module also has the DCC.

Comment: @rschwieb sorry, that "right $\mathcal{C}$-approximation" was meant to be "$\mathcal{C}$-precover", fixed that.

Do you know a better choice for that $\theta$? Does this attempt lead to a solution at all?

Comment: If you want to see a proof, one can be found at Theorem 5.8 of *Elements of the Representation Theory of Associative Algebras, Volume 1* by Assem, Simson and Skowronski. Their proof is very dependent on properties of finite dimensional algebras.

Comment: @Zeek thank you very much!